# How to share Razor components with the need for interactivity in a Razor Class Library (.Net 8)

Tags: c#, blazor, maui-blazor, .net-8.0, razor-class-library

I have created a MAUI Blazor App and a Blazor WEB App (.NET 8) and a common Razor Class Library using out of the box projects.

My problem is the how to put the Counter.Razor page into the Razor Class Library. The Counter.Razor file needs interactivity, so in the Web App-version there is the line:

`@rendermode InteractiveAuto`

This line is not recognized by the MAUI Blazor Hybrid app, so this will give an compiler error.

If the line is deleted, the MAUI Blazor Hybrid app will work as expected, but the Web App will have no interactivity.

What is the correct/best way to share Razor components with the need for interactivity in a Razor Class Library?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/class-libraries-and-static-server-side-rendering?view=aspnetcore-8.0#when-to-use-the-rendermode-directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [Ms Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/class-libraries-and-static-server-side-rendering?view=aspnetcore-8.0#when-to-use-the-rendermode-directive), that @Brian linked in the comments.

> In most cases, reusable component authors should not specify a render mode, even when interactivity is required. This is because the component author doesn't know whether the app enables support for InteractiveServer, InteractiveWebAssembly, or both with InteractiveAuto. By not specifying a @rendermode, the component author leaves the choice to the app developer.

It's recommended to not declare `@rendermode` in the components that are in a Razor Class Library, instead they should be applied the `@rendermode` when the component is instantiated.
e.g.

```html
<Counter @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
```

Comment: I'm aware of this, but the Counter is called form a NavLink, where I think one cannot set the rendermode. The solution I can se, is to add the Counter.Razor file to the Common Razor Class Libery, without the rendermode line. Then in the Blazor WebApp.Client one creates a wrapper around the Counter using your suggestion, and then call this warpper from the NavLink and from the Blazor Hybrid app the Counter can be called directly from the NavLink.

Comment: Please check this answer, may it help you, https://stackoverflow.com/a/77554386/1606054

Comment: Yes my suggestion is to seperate the Counter page from the Counter component. The page stays in the app, the component goes in the RCL