# InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode not working when navigate to shared library page

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-8

I am using Blazor Web App template introduced in .Net Core 8.0

I want to render Blazor pages as `InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode` that are shared between different projects. So I created a shared Razor class library.

It works fine when I use `InteractiveAutoRenderMode` or move the .razor file to .Client project, but as soon as I move the .razor file to shared project it starts giving me error. `Root component type 'Frontend.Interface.Pages.Job' could not be found in the assembly 'Frontend.Interface.Pages'.`

As long as I copy all the pages into the *.Client project, everything works fine. (Server rendering and Client rendering)
How can I tell the *.Client project that all pages are stored in a different project? Is there anything like this `AdditionalAssemblies=new[] { typeof(MyPage).Assembly}`?
Or is it not possible at the moment?

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/class-libraries-and-static-server-side-rendering?view=aspnetcore-8.0#when-to-use-the-rendermode-directive and this question and answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77538649/how-to-share-razor-components-with-the-need-for-interactivity-in-a-razor-class-l

Comment: I already read that documentation, but the problem is that my pages are routable components therefore I am not calling them inside another component, I am calling them via NavLink, where I cannot define the render mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around of my problem, it was because of tree shaking, while trying to use a WebAssemblyRenderMode content from a razor class library project.

I had to write a reference of my WebAssembly component type in my client Main method before calling RunAsyc.

```
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

var type = typeof(WebAssemblyRenderedPage);

//Register your client side services here

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26601#issuecomment-1125036157